# "getDeliveredNotificationsWithCompletionHandler" gives notification tray count zero : iOS12.1

Tags: objective-c, push-notification, nsnotificationcenter, unnotificationrequest

**Follow below steps**

> 1. Open the app
> 2. Lock the iPad using the lock button
> 3. Then send the notification from backend-- device receives notification in the notification tray
> 4. Then unlock the iPad using the lock button The app is still open since we have not pressed the Home button yet.
> 5. Now when we perform "getDeliveredNotificationsWithCompletionHandler" gives notification
>      tray count zero - it should give the count that 1 notification is
>      received. **[ IT ALSO DOES NOT GIVE ME CORRECT COUNT WHEN I PUT MY APP TO BACKGROUND AND THEN I MAKE IT FOREGROUND ]**

This is the my code:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

    [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] getDeliveredNotificationsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray<UNNotification *> * _Nonnull notifications) {

        NSLog(@"getDeliveredNotificationsWithCompletionHandler count %lu", [notifications count]);

        for (UNNotification* notification in notifications) {
            // do something with object
            [self handlePushNotification:notification.request.content.userInfo];
        }

        if(notifications.count) {
            [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] removeAllDeliveredNotifications];
        }

    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This issue is in the notification payload from server side -  It was like below**

```
{
    aps =     {
        alert =         {
            body = "";
            title = "";
        };
        badge = 1;
    };

}
```

> ** But when i have made the badge value to "0" then i got the count from getDeliveredNotificationsWithCompletionHandler**

```
  {
        aps =     {
            alert =         {
                body = "";
                title = "";
            };
            badge = 0;
        };

    }
```